# Items flicker when reordering using bloc on a ReorderableList in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm working on a reorderable list, and I'm having an issue when the list is reordered.

As you can see in the video, once the list is reordered, the items flicker.  However, this only happens if I use a `bloc` to handle that state, if I use `setState` nothing flickers and everything works smoothly.

Also, it only happens in web... Tried as a mac app and works fine with bloc.

Currently using flutter 3.10.0, but also tried with 3.7.12 with same results.

I've tried getting the list with a `watch` a `select` and a `BlocBuilder` but got the same results.

[image: Flicker example]

Here's a sample app to reproduce the issue:

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => MainBloc(),
        child: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Comment out this when using Bloc.
  // List<String> items = [
  //   '1 - This is the first item',
  //   '2 - Second item here',
  //   '3 - Maybe the third item?'
  // ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Comment out this line when using SetState.
    final items = context.select((MainBloc bloc) => bloc.state.items);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ReorderableList(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final value = items[index];
            return _ListItem(
              key: ValueKey(index),
              index: index,
              value: value,
            );
          },
          itemCount: items.length,
          onReorderStart: (index) {},
          onReorderEnd: (index) {},
          onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
            // Comment out the SetState when using Bloc.
            // setState(() {
            //   final updatedNewIndex =
            //       oldIndex < newIndex ? newIndex - 1 : newIndex;
            //   final updatedItems = [...items];
            //   final item = updatedItems.removeAt(oldIndex);
            //   updatedItems.insert(updatedNewIndex, item);
            //   items = updatedItems;
            // });

            // Comment out this when using SetState.
            context.read<MainBloc>().add(ItemsReordered(oldIndex, newIndex));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ListItem({
    required super.key,
    required this.index,
    required this.value,
  });

  final int index;
  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ReorderableDragStartListener(
              index: index,
              child: const MouseRegion(
                cursor: SystemMouseCursors.grab,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.drag_indicator,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: TextField(
                enabled: false,
                readOnly: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
                controller: TextEditingController(text: value),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 12),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainBloc extends Bloc<ItemsReordered, MainState> {
  MainBloc() : super(const MainState()) {
    on<ItemsReordered>(_onItemsReordered);
  }

  void _onItemsReordered(
    ItemsReordered event,
    Emitter<MainState> emit,
  ) {
    final oldIndex = event.oldIndex;
    final newIndex = event.newIndex;
    final updatedNewIndex = oldIndex < newIndex ? newIndex - 1 : newIndex;

    final items = [...state.items];
    final element = items.removeAt(oldIndex);
    items.insert(updatedNewIndex, element);

    emit(
      state.copyWith(items: items),
    );
  }
}

class MainState extends Equatable {
  const MainState({
    this.items = const [
      '1 - This is the first item',
      '2 - Second item here',
      '3 - Maybe the third item?',
    ],
  });

  final List<String> items;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [items];

  MainState copyWith({List<String>? items}) {
    return MainState(items: items ?? this.items);
  }
}

class ItemsReordered extends Equatable {
  const ItemsReordered(this.oldIndex, this.newIndex);

  final int oldIndex;
  final int newIndex;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [oldIndex, newIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It flickers because:

1. `ReorderableList` animates the drag and drop ("faking" the state change) and then triggers a rebuild when the user stops interacting.
2. The rebuild just re-uses the old values, because the `Bloc` is asynchronous and the `ItemsReordered` event hasn't finished processing yet, so no new values are passed down to each `_ListItem`.
3. `BlocBuilder` finishes processing the event and triggers a second rebuild with the updated values.

The solution is to use the `BlocBuilder`'s `buildWhen` parameter to specifically ignore changes to the order of the list. We then add a new stateful widget (`ListOrganizer`) to track the order of items in the list and forward any ordering changes to the `Bloc`.

Here is the sample app with the changes:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => MainBloc(),
        child: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<MainBloc, MainState>(
          bloc: context.read<MainBloc>(),
          buildWhen: (previous, current) {
            // The bloc will only rebuild if the number of items or the value contents change.
            // Changes to the order of the items doesn't trigger a rebuild.
            final sortedPreviousItems = [...previous.items]..sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));
            final sortedCurrentItems = [...current.items]..sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));
            if (!listEquals(sortedPreviousItems, sortedCurrentItems)) {
              return true;
            }

            return false;
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            return ListOrganizer(
              items: state.items,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ListOrganizer maintains the order of the items in the list, and relays changes back to MainBloc.
class ListOrganizer extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListOrganizer({super.key, required this.items});

  final List<Item> items;

  @override
  State<ListOrganizer> createState() => _ListOrganizerState();
}

class _ListOrganizerState extends State<ListOrganizer> {
  List<Item> itemsCache = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    itemsCache = widget.items;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ListOrganizer oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (oldWidget.items != widget.items) {
      setState(() {
        itemsCache = widget.items;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (itemsCache.isEmpty) {
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    }
    return ReorderableList(
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return _ListItem(
          key: ValueKey(itemsCache[i].value),
          index: i,
          value: itemsCache[i].value,
        );
      },
      itemCount: itemsCache.length,
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
        // Update the cached list of items, triggering the UI to update
        final updatedNewIndex = oldIndex < newIndex ? newIndex - 1 : newIndex;
        var items = [...itemsCache];
        final item = items.removeAt(oldIndex);
        items.insert(updatedNewIndex, item);

        // setState is not required for ReorderableList to work, but it's a good practice to use it
        setState(() {
          itemsCache = items;
        });

        // Update the bloc, the buildWhen condition in the BlocBuilder will prevent a rebuild
        context.read<MainBloc>().add(ItemsReordered(oldIndex, newIndex));
      },
    );
  }
}

class _ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ListItem({
    required super.key,
    required this.index,
    required this.value,
  });

  final int index;
  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ReorderableDragStartListener(
              index: index,
              child: const MouseRegion(
                cursor: SystemMouseCursors.grab,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.drag_indicator,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: TextField(
                enabled: false,
                readOnly: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
                controller: TextEditingController(text: value),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 12),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainBloc extends Bloc<ItemsReordered, MainState> {
  MainBloc() : super(const MainState()) {
    on<ItemsReordered>(_onItemsReordered);
  }

  void _onItemsReordered(
    ItemsReordered event,
    Emitter<MainState> emit,
  ) {
    final oldIndex = event.oldIndex;
    final newIndex = event.newIndex;
    final updatedNewIndex = oldIndex < newIndex ? newIndex - 1 : newIndex;

    final items = [...state.items];
    final movedItem = items.removeAt(oldIndex);
    items.insert(updatedNewIndex, movedItem);

    emit(
      state.copyWith(items: items),
    );
  }
}

class MainState extends Equatable {
  const MainState({
    this.items = const [
      Item('aaa', '1 - This is the first item'),
      Item('bbb', '2 - Second item here'),
      Item('ccc', '3 - Maybe the third item?'),
    ],
  });

  final List<Item> items;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [items];

  MainState copyWith({List<Item>? items}) {
    return MainState(
      items: items ?? this.items,
    );
  }
}

class Item extends Equatable {
  const Item(this.id, this.value);

  final String id;
  final String value;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id, value];
}

class ItemsReordered extends Equatable {
  const ItemsReordered(this.oldIndex, this.newIndex);

  final int oldIndex;
  final int newIndex;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [oldIndex, newIndex];
}

// Helper class to print out bloc events
class AppBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object? event) {
    super.onEvent(bloc, event);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("onEvent $event");
    }
  }

  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("onChange $change");
    }
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("onTransition $transition");
    }
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("onError $error");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that `bloc` updates asynchronously. `ReorderableListView` re-renders after calling `onReorder` but before `BlocBuilder` has updated.

I found the simplest solution is to wrap `ReorderableListView` with a stateful component that caches the list, allowing it to be updated in `onReorder` and then overwritten when `BlocBuilder` updates.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef ListItemWidgetBuilder<T> = Widget Function(
    BuildContext context, T item);

class CachedReorderableListView<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const CachedReorderableListView(
      {required this.list,
      required this.itemBuilder,
      required this.onReorder,
      super.key});

  final List<T> list;
  final ListItemWidgetBuilder<T> itemBuilder;
  final ReorderCallback onReorder;

  @override
  CachedReorderableListViewState<T> createState() =>
      CachedReorderableListViewState<T>();
}

class CachedReorderableListViewState<T>
    extends State<CachedReorderableListView<T>> {
  late List<T> list;

  @override
  void initState() {
    list = [...widget.list];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant CachedReorderableListView<T> oldWidget) {
    if (widget.list != oldWidget.list) {
      list = [...widget.list];
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  void updateList(List<T> value) {
    setState(() {
      list = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => widget.itemBuilder(context, list[index]),
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final item = list.removeAt(oldIndex);
          list.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
        widget.onReorder(oldIndex, newIndex);
      },
    );
  }
}

// Then in your widget
CachedReorderableListView(
  onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
    // Generate a bloc event
  },
  list: yourList,
  itemBuilder: (context, item) {
    // render a list item
  },
);
```